# Does Dual Wielder let an Eldritch Knight summon two bonded weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, feats, fighter

### Background

I'm trying to make a master thrower character, and the fighter class seems to be the best option. However, since thrown weapons don't follow the same rules as ammo-based weapons, I've been trying to figure out how to draw more than one weapon at a time to throw.

I came up with the idea of an eldritch knight who has bonded with 2 darts and uses the dual wielder feat to summon them both at the same time.

### The Rules in Question

The eldritch knight's weapon bond feature:

> Once you have bonded a weapon to yourself…you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn…You can have up to two bonded weapons but can summon only one at a time with your bonus action.

The Dual Wielder feat:

> - You can draw or stow two one-handed weapons when you would normally be able to draw or stow only one.

### My Question

Does dual wielder's third bullet point allow an eldritch knight to summon both bonded weapons with their bonus action?

Or is *summoning* a weapon completely different from *drawing* one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

***Summoning* is not *drawing.***

Sorry, but they're not the same word, and drawing is not a superset of summoning. So there's no reason for a rule that modifies *drawing* a weapon to have any effect on *summoning* a weapon.