# Can You Two-Weapon Fight With Thrown Ranged Weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, combat, ranged-attack, throwing-things

A spin-off question from an [earlier post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77311/16370), can you two-weapon fight with a dart or other thrown ranged weapons?

> **Two-Weapon Fighting**
>   When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand. You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.
>
> If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee attack with it.

–PH page 195

Assuming you have the dual wielder feat which allows you to ignore the "light weapon" clause.

I read the second paragraph to mean that if the *melee weapon* has the thrown property you can throw *the melee weapon*.

However, another RPG.SX user reads it as if the *weapon* has the thrown property, you can throw *the weapon*, melee or not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the rule you quote:

> If either weapon has the thrown property...

Which weapon(s)?

> a light melee weapon... [and] a different light melee weapon.

So the weapons of "either weapon" mention *are* the light **melee** weapons from the previous paragraph.

**You can't throw both darts, because they're not valid weapons for two-weapon fighting.**

And neither is a melee weapon, so:

**You can't make improvised (dagger?) melee attacks with both.**

---

*But doesn't using a dart as an improvised dagger make it a melee weapon? "Improvised Weapons" (PHB p.147-148) says "in many cases, an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon **and can be treated as such.**" (emphasis mine)*

Nope. Later in "Improvised Weapons" we have "if a character uses a ranged weapon **to make a melee attack**...." (emphasis mine) The authors could have said "ranged weapon **as** a melee weapon" or something that indicated some change in the weapon's type, but they didn't.

It's still a ranged weapon, per the table, even when used to make a melee attack.

Comment: [Relevant Crawford ruling](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/951154170748321792): "If a game feature says it works with a melee weapon, it means an actual melee weapon."