# What is the maximum number of net attacks that one can make in a round?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, attack

I'm trying to net (ha) as many thrown attacks using the ever-so-special [net](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/net). There's a big hurdle, however.

> [snip]... When you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to attack with a net, you can make only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

## How many net attacks can be made by a character in one round?

---

Constraints:

- Point Buy (27 point) attribute generation
- No magic items
- Official sources only (No 3rd party; No UA; Eberron is okay)
- Any level
- Multiclassing is allowed
- Does not have to be good at net throwing, just able to throw a lot of them
- Feats are allowed.
- You may have one noncombat preparatory round
- Answer goes to whomever can throw the most nets in one round

  - ties go to whoever is better at throwing nets
- Help from another is not allowed

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94566/discussion-on-question-by-goodguy5-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-net-attacks-tha).

Comment: Part of our fine [cheese collection](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7218/23970).

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77323/44723

Comment: Are summoned minions allowed to throw nets?

Comment: @Murphy I'll say yes, as long as (obviously), you're the one that summons them.

Answer (score 27):

**A character can pull off ∞ with perfect rolls (or as many nets as you have)**
*Thanks to [@Ko_sct](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/46905/ko-sct) in the comments for this strategy*

### The Character

Any level 17 Wild Magic sorcerer can accomplish this using:

- Wild Magic Surge
- *time stop*
- the Dual Wielder feat

### The Loop

1. Cast *time stop*
2. Trigger Wild Magic Surge
3. Roll a 1 on the d20
4. Roll a 59-60 on the d100
5. Throw nets throughout *time stop* until the last turn of *time stop*
6. Draw two nets (possible because of Dual Wielder) as part of your movement when necessary.
7. On the last turn of *time stop* repeat steps 1-4

As long as you continually roll 59-60 and never run out of nets, you can do this forever.

### How many nets?

The highest carrying capacity a level 20 sorcerer can get is:

- A goliath, bugbear, orc, firbolg, centaur, or loxodon
- with 30 Strength (gained through Epic Boons)
- the High Magic Epic Boon
- having used a 9th level spell slot to cast *enlarge/reduce* becoming Large.

This lets you carry 1,800 pounds which comes to 590 nets in 20 sacks.

*Of course if you can just pull from a pile of nets, then the maximum number of nets is arbitrarily large.*

However, if you are interested in a strategy to throw nets a little bit faster, see my previous strategy below:

---

**The most a single character can throw is 37**

### The Character

The character, let's call her Celeste from here on out, that can throw the most nets is a level 20 character with the following classes:

- Sorcerer (Wild Magic) 17 ------ (for Wild Magic Surge, Flexible Casting, Quickened Spell, the Dual Wielder feat, and spells)
- Fighter 2 ------------------------ (for Action Surge)
- Cleric (War Domain) 1 --------- (for War Priest)

..., at least 20 Wisdom, and the Boon of High Magic

### The Preparation

For Celeste's preparation round, she follows the following procedure:

1. Cast *haste* with the Quickened Spell Metamagic.
2. Roll a 1 on the d20 for Wild Magic Surge.
3. Roll 01-02 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge.
4. Take the Ready action to throw a net at the start of the round.
5. Use the effect of *haste* to take the Use an Object action and draw your first two nets of many.

### The Throwing

Now that Celeste has prepared, she throws her nets:

- First off, she throw the net she had readied, then her turn begins:

**Normal Turn**

1. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge.
2. Throw a net. ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [total so far: **2**]
3. Draw two nets as part of your movement.
4. Throw a net. ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [**3**]
5. Use War Priest to throw a net. ------------------------------------------------- [**4**]
6. Use the effect of *haste* to take the Use an Object action and draw two nets.
7. Use Action Surge.
8. Cast *time stop* rolling a 4 on the 1d4.

**Turn One of *Time Stop***

9. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge.
10. Throw a net. ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [**5**]
11. Cast *ray of sickness* with the Quickened Spell Metamagic on an empty space (use Bend Luck)
12. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge to recover Bend Luck.
13. Throw a net. ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [**6**]
14. Draw two nets as part of your movement.
15. Throw a net at an empty space. ------------------------------------------------ [**7**]
16. Use the *haste* action to throw a net at an empty space. --------------------- [**8**]

**Turn Two of *Time Stop***

17. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge.
18. Take the Use an Object action to draw two nets.
19. Throw a net at an empty space. ------------------------------------------------ [**9**]
20. Use War Priest to throw a net at an empty space. --------------------------- [**10**]
21. Draw two nets as part of your movement.
22. Use the *haste* action to throw a net at an empty space. --------------------- [**11**]

**Turn Three of *Time Stop***

23. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge.
24. Throw a net. ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [**12**]
25. Cast *ray of sickness* with the Quickened Spell Metamagic on an empty space (use Bend Luck).
26. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge to recover Bend Luck.
27. Take the Use an Object action to draw two nets.
28. Throw a net at an empty space. ------------------------------------------------ [**13**]
29. Use the *haste* action to throw a net at an empty space. --------------------- [**14**]
30. Draw two nets as part of your movement.

**Turn Four of *Time Stop***

31. Repeat steps 9-11. --------------------------------------------------------------- [**18**]

**Turn Five of First *Time Stop***

32. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge.
33. Take the Use an Object action to draw two nets.
34. Use the *haste* action to throw a net at an empty space. --------------------- [**19**]
35. Use War Priest to throw a net at an empty space. --------------------------- [**20**]
36. Draw two nets as part of your movement.
37. Repeat steps 8-26. -------------------------------------------------------------- [**34**]

**Turn Five of Second *Time Stop***

38. Roll 81-82 on the d100 for Wild Magic Surge.
39. Take the Use an Object action to draw two nets.
40. Throw a net at an empty space. ----------------------------------------------- [**35**]
41. Use War Priest to throw a net at an empty space. -------------------------- [**36**]
42. Draw your last net as part of your movement.
43. Use *haste* action to throw a net. ---------------------------------------------- [**37**]

### The Probability

First of all, your GM has to allow you to roll on the Wild Magic Surge table (to recover Bend Luck) every time you cast *ray of sickness*, and to have the chance when you cast *haste*. This is already extremely unlikely. Then there are the actual rolls.

I changed the procedure a few times to try to get the best odds of this completing. The rolls necessary are listed below (keep in mind that a high level Wild Magic sorcerer can roll twice on the table and choose either result via Controlled Chaos | Thanks for the mention in the comments [@Speedkat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/36469/speedkat)):

- 1 on the d20 one time

  - (1/20)
- 1 or 2 on the d100 one time

  - 1-(98/100)<sup>2</sup>
- 81 or 82 on the d100 nineteen times

  - (1-(98/100)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>19</sup>
- 4 on the d4 two times

  - (1/4)<sup>2</sup>

Multiplying these probablities comes to one chance in just over three nonillion (or 3,558,330,300,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 in numerical (rounded))

If we take the average number of times we roll 81-82 on the d100, then our probability drops considerably to one in 8,081, but we only get an **average of 20.6732 nets**

Or we can take the average result for all Wild Magic Surges dropping our probability to one in sixteen, but we only get an **average of 20.001 nets**

---

<sup>1</sup> You have to target an empty space with *ray of sickness* and the nets during *time stop* so that the spell doesn't end:

> This spell ends if one of the actions you use during this period, or any effects that you create during this period, affects a creature other than you or an object being worn or carried by someone other than you.

Attacking empty spaces is perfectly valid according to the [Making an Attack section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack) of the Basic Rules (***emphasis*** mine):

> **1. Choose a target.** Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, or ***a location***.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94609/discussion-on-answer-by-david-coffron-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-net-attacks).

Answer (score 10):

## 4 nets in one round in those conditions

Fighter 2 / War Cleric 1 with the Dual Wielder feat.

**Round 1.**

Use your action to ready an attack action with one of your nets.

**Round 2.**

Right before your turn, you use your reaction to throw your first net. Then on your turn you use an Attack action to throw your second net. You then use your free object interaction to draw two nets (instead of one because of the dual wielder feat). Using the the *war priest* feature of the cleric's war domain allows you to make an attack as a bonus action, allowing you to throw a third net.

> **War Priest.** [...] When you use the Attack action, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action. [...]

You then use *Action Surge* to make another attack and throw your fourth and last net.

### Note

The Cleric's War Domain (or a Path of the Berserker Barbarian's frenzy) is needed, because as written, the dual fighting does not work with nets. They aren't melee weapons, they are considered ranged weapons.

The ready action can be replaced by an extra action given by the spell *haste*, but both cannot be used together simply because you run out of nets in your hands.

### Extra

The absolute maximum of nets that you can throw in a single round seems to be 6, but for that you need allies.
Use the spell *Shapechange* to assume the form of a Marilith so that you can have 6 nets ready in your hand. Use the *haste* spell to add another action allowing you to throw a fifth net. Then another one of your allies uses the *Commander's Strike* maneuver, allowing you to use your reaction (that you gained back at the start of your turn) to throw a sixth and final net.

Comment: I'm reading war domain, and maybe I'm just missing it, but were in the description does it allow you to use ranged weapons with Dual Wielder?

Comment: @G.Moylan It doesn't. The war priest allow you to make an attack as a bonus action. The Dual Wielder feats allow you to draw 2 weapons instead one when 1 in situation where you could draw one and you are normally a free object interaction (such as drawing 1 weapon) every turn. Without the feat you'd draw a single a single net and wouldn't have one in hand for the last attack.

Comment: @G.Moylan I added the text from War Priest to clarify. The wording includes ranged weapons—also to my surprise. ;)

Answer (score 8):

## 5 nets

Though it relies on quite a bit of luck.
**Class:** Sorcerer 5 (wild) / Rogue 3 (thief) / Fighter 2, Dual Wielder feat.

**Preparatory Round:**
Cast *Quickened Haste* as a bonus action, and roll a 01-02 on the wild magic table (roll at start of every turn for next minute). Draw two nets. Ready an action to throw a net.

**Execution Round:**
Reaction triggers, throw a net. (1)

**Execution Round, during turn:**
Roll 81-82 on wild magic table (take one additional action immediately)
Wild Action - throw a net. Draw two nets. (2)
Regular Action - throw a net. (3)
Haste Action - throw a net. (4)
Bonus Action - Cunning Action - Draw two nets.
Action Surge - throw a net. (5)

Comment: [Opportunity attacks must be melee attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks)

Comment: To be specific, this has a 1/2500 chance of working as laid out here.

Answer (score 2):

(intended as a baseline value)

## A Level-2 Fighter can make 3 net attacks.

Variant Human With the Dual Wielder feat.
Stats: S16; D8; C16; I8; W15; C8

#### Prep Round:

- Have two nets drawn
- Ready an action to throw a net.

#### Go-time:

1. Use readied action before your turn starts to throw 1 net
2. Attack Action 2nd net
3. Object interaction to draw two more nets
4. Action Surge a 3rd net
5. If a reaction attack becomes available, you can use it to throw a 4th net

   - Though, I don't know of any way to use your reaction to throw a net.